# How to do a database lock in AppEngine (GAE)?

Tags: google-app-engine, concurrency, locking

In GAE, I've got a table full of "one offs" -- things like "last-used sequence number" and the like that don't really fall into other tables.  It's a simple String-key with String-value pair.

I've got some code to grab a named integer and increment it, like so:

```
@PersistenceCapable(detachable="true")
public class OneOff
{
    @PrimaryKey
    @Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
    private Key key;

    @Persistent
    private String dataKey;

    @Persistent
    private String value;


    public OneOff(String kk, String vv)
    {
        this.dataKey = kk;
        this.value = vv;
    }


    public static OneOff persistOneOff(String kk, String vv)
    {
        OneOff oneoff= new OneOff(kk, vv);
        PersistenceManager pm = PMF.get().getPersistenceManager();
        try
        {
            pm.makePersistent(oneoff);
        }
        finally
        {
            pm.close();
        }

        return oneoff;
    }


    // snip...
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    synchronized
    public static int getIntValueForKeyAndIncrement(String kk, int deFltValue)
    {
        int result = 0;
        OneOff oneOff = null;

        PersistenceManager pm = PMF.get().getPersistenceManager();
        Query query = pm.newQuery(OneOff.class);
        query.setFilter("dataKey == kkParam");
        query.declareParameters("String kkParam");
        List<OneOff> oneOffs = (List<OneOff>) query.execute(kk);

        int count = oneOffs.size();
        if (count == 1)
        {
            oneOff = oneOffs.get(0);
            result = Integer.parseInt(oneOff.value);
        }
        else if (count == 0)
        {
            oneOff = new OneOff(kk, "default");
            result = deFltValue;
        }
        else
        {
                // Log WTF error.
        }

        // update object in DB.
        oneOff.value = "" + (result+1);
        try
        {
            pm.makePersistent(oneOff);
        }
        finally
        {
            pm.close();
        }

        return result;
    }
    // etc...
```

However, when I make these calls:

```
int val1 = OneOff.getIntValueForKeyAndIncrement("someKey", 100);
int val2 = OneOff.getIntValueForKeyAndIncrement("someKey", 100);
int val3 = OneOff.getIntValueForKeyAndIncrement("someKey", 100);
```

Sometimes I get the desired increment and sometimes I get the same value.  It appears that my DB access is running asynchronously, when I'd like to lock the DB for this particular transaction.

I thought that

```
    synchronized
    public static
```

was supposed to do that for me, but apparently not (probably due to multiple instances running!)

At any rate -- how do I do the thing that I want?  (I want to lock my DB while I get & update this value, to make the whole thing concurrency-safe.)

Thanks!

**== EDIT ==**

I have accepted Robert's as the correct answer, since transactions were, indeed, what I wanted.  However, for completeness, I have added my updated code below.  I think it's correct, although I'm not sure about the `if(oneOff==null)` clause (the try-catch bit.)

```
public static int getIntValueForKeyAndIncrement(String kk, int defltValue)
{
    int result = 0;
    Entity oneOff = null;
    int retries = 3;

    // Using Datastore Transactions
    DatastoreService datastore = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();
    while (true)
    {
        com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Transaction txn = datastore.beginTransaction();
        try
        {
            Key oneOffKey = KeyFactory.createKey("OneOff", kk);
            oneOff = datastore.get (oneOffKey);
            result = Integer.parseInt((String) oneOff.getProperty("value"));
            oneOff.setProperty("value",  "" + (result+1));
            datastore.put(oneOff);
            txn.commit();
            break;
        }
        catch (EntityNotFoundException ex)
        {
            result = defltValue;
        }
        catch (ConcurrentModificationException ex)
        {
            if (--retries < 0)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }

        if (oneOff == null)
        {
            try
            {
                Key oneOffKey = KeyFactory.createKey("OneOff", kk);
                oneOff = new Entity(oneOffKey);
                oneOff.setProperty("value",  "" + (defltValue+1));
                datastore.put(txn, oneOff);
                datastore.put(oneOff);
                txn.commit();
                break;
            }
            finally
            {
                if (txn.isActive())
                {
                    txn.rollback();
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (txn.isActive())
            {
                txn.rollback();
            }
        }
    }
return result;
}
```

Comment: The fact that you're trying to do this in the first place is a code smell - your app is very unlikely to scale well at all with these sort of global locks. Are you aware App Engine provides built in support for allocating unique IDs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be updating your values inside a [transaction](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/transactions.html).  App Engine's transactions will prevent two updates from overwriting each other as long as your read and write are within a single transaction.  Be sure to pay attention to the discussion about entity groups.

Comment: you don't really need to care about entity groups here if you're just updating a single value.

Comment: @andrew, that is true. However, if he were to try extending this to query for the existing value it could become an issue.

Comment: i'm not sure i follow (maybe i have misunderstood the data store myself), but a single value with no parent (as this would be) forms its own little group.  so you can read it and update it in a transaction.

Comment: @andrew, correct it is in its own entity group.  The main point is that App Engine transactions are limited to operating on a single entity group.  That means you can *not* perform a query fetching multiple entities, unless it is an ancestor query (one entity group) within a transaction.  You are only allowed to fetch an entity by key or with an ancestor query.