# How to avoid concurrent data modifications in GAE Datastore

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, objectify

Let’s say below is the GAE data store kind, where the need is to store two different players info into a single entity, how the data correctness can be maintained?

```
@Entity
public class Game
{
    id
    player1Id
    player2Id
    score1
    score2
}
```

Let say player1 wants to modify score1, he first reads the entity and modifies score1 and saves back into datastore.

Similarly player2 wants to modify score2, he as well first reads the entity and modifies score2 and saves back into datastore.

So having this functionality, there is a chance that both player1 and player2 try to modify the same entity and they could end up modifying the data incorrectly due to a dirty read.

Is there a way to avoid the dirty reads with GAE Data store to make sure the data correctness (or) avoid the concurrent modification?

Comment: As the other answers says, you need to use transactions. Consider also a roll forward transaction model. Have a read of this article by Nick Johnson on the topic, the examples are python but it equally applies to java http://blog.notdot.net/2009/9/Distributed-Transactions-on-App-Engine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Transactions:

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/transactions

> When two or more transactions simultaneously attempt to modify
>   entities in one or more common entity groups, only the first
>   transaction to commit its changes can succeed; all the others will
>   fail on commit.

Comment: I understand that but in few cases we cannot just fail the other transaction, so is there a way to avoid the dirty read by the second transaction before it can commit?

Comment: perhaps relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6963510/how-to-do-a-database-lock-in-appengine-gae

Answer (score 3):

You need to use [Transactions](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/transactions), and then you have two options:

1. Implement your own logic for transaction failures (how many times to retry, etc.)
2. Instead of writing to the datastore directly, create a [task](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/taskqueue/overview-push) to modify an entity. Run a transaction inside a task. If it fails, the App Engine will retry this task until it succeeds.

Comment: Could you provide bit more info on Tasks please? How to use them in my scenario? Also I would assume that one Task will do one transaction and like that how many tasks can we have simultaneously running?

Comment: I updated my answer with more details. Also, you can configure your tasks execution rate - you can execute as many per second as you need.

Comment: Thanks Andrei Volgin. Appreciate your suggestions.